# 500 internal server error Laravel 5

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, internal-server-error

I'm receiving an internal server error on Laravel 5.

My .htaccess files (both one at root and one in /public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My log:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
>   probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: what is your `doc root` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `/public` directory .htaccess, you are rewriting urls to point at `/public` again, so it is endlessly rewriting the url.  In the `/public` htaccess file, the rule would be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Check out the `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel for reference:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess